# function as parametr in function

Tags: php, function, arguments

I need give function as argument function. 
For example

```
<i>$smoothFunc = smooth(function ($sum) {
  return sin(rad2deg($sum));
}, 15);
```

$smoothFunc(10) // ~ 0.438

How i can do this?

This code not work

```
$arg1=function($a,$b){
  return $a+$b;
};

function smoothFunc($arg1, $dx){
  return $f1($a,$b)+$dx;
};

echo (smoothFunc(arg1(2,3),1));*/
```

Comment: Call to undefined function `arg12()` So where is the `arg12()` function

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function arg12($a,$b){
  return $a+$b;
};
function f1($a,$b){
    return $a+$b;
}
function smoothFunc($a, $b, $dx){
  return f1($a,$b)+$dx;
};

echo (smoothFunc(arg12(2,3), 2, 1));
```

pleae don't assine a function into variable and create a function with first place `"$"`.

More Details here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: You Can assign a function into variable in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Create the function separately for usability!

```
function smooth($sum) {
    return sin(rad2deg($sum));
}
$smoothFunc = smooth(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function arg1($a,$b){
  return $a+$b;
};

function smoothFunc($pArg1, $pDx){
  return $pArg1+$pDx;
};

echo (smoothFunc(arg1(2,3),1));
```